# mysql limit clause in having - is it a bug?

Tags: mysql, having

I have tested two queries on two servers, and identical datasets. I got the same results in 3 cases, and wrong result in one case.
Servers: MySQL  5.1.73 (running on RHEL linux) and MySQL 5.7.11 (running on windows 7)
My queries are below.
On the 5.1.73 server plan A or plan B returns 854 rows.
On the 5.7.11 server plan A returns 854 rows. Plan B returns only 1 row!
Remark: docchange.HID is unique (unsigned integer).

**Is this a bug?**   Is it fixed in newer versions?
  Plan B is faster on the production server, but gives wrong results on the development server, and the production server may be upgraded to 5.7.x in the future, wich would break functionality for users ..

The two queries:

-- plan A

```
select r1.doknr, r1.dokcm , r1.HID  
from  
(SELECT * FROM docdistro  WHERE ( (docdistro.tdate_begin) Between '2016-01-01 00:00:00' and '2016-12-01 00:00:00' ))  AS d1  
INNER JOIN (
    select DID, HID, doktype, doknr, dokcm 
    from docchange as docchange_1 
    where ( (`docchange_1`.HID)
            = ( Select d2.hid from docchange as d2
                where d2.did = `docchange_1`.did order by HID asc
                limit 1))
) AS r1 ON d1.DID = r1.DID
GROUP BY  r1.doknr, r1.dokcm , r1.HID, r1.DID ;
```

-- plan B

```
select r1.doknr, r1.dokcm , r1.HID  
from  
(SELECT * FROM docdistro  WHERE ( (docdistro.tdate_begin) Between '2016-01-01 00:00:00' and '2016-12-01 00:00:00' ))  AS d1  
INNER JOIN (
    select DID, HID, doktype, doknr, dokcm 
    from docchange) AS r1 ON d1.DID = r1.DID  
GROUP BY  r1.doknr, r1.dokcm , r1.HID, r1.DID 
HAVING  (
    r1.HID = (
        Select docchange.hid
        from docchange
        where docchange.did = r1.DID
        order by HID asc
        limit 1 )
) ;
```

**Update**: Test database & test queries added. Query A1, A2, A4, B4 works propely on both servers. Query B1, B2 works on MySQL 5.1.73. They return no records on MySQL 5.7.11. Query A3, B3 works on MySQL 5.1.73, and gives an error message on 5.7.11. They work properly on 5.7.11 if  sql_mode=only_full_group_by" is turned off. I think that query B1, B2 should work the same way on both servers, but they don't. Is this a bug?

Expected query output:

cfgID | mid | did   | HID | DID | docname
1     |  1  |   1   |  1  | 1   | doc1v1
2     |  1  |   2   |  3  | 2   | doc2v1
3     |  2  |   2   |  3  | 2   | doc2v1

**Test database**:
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `t1`;
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `cfgID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `did` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cfgID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `cfgID_UNIQUE` (`cfgID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8   COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

LOCK TABLES `t1` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `t1` DISABLE KEYS */;

INSERT INTO `t1` VALUES (1,1,1),(2,1,2),(3,2,2);

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `t1` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `t2`;
CREATE TABLE `t2` (
  `HID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `docname` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`HID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `HID_UNIQUE` (`HID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8   COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

LOCK TABLES `t2` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `t2` DISABLE KEYS */;

INSERT INTO `t2` VALUES (1,1,'doc1v1'),(2,1,'doc1v2'),(3,2,'doc2v1'),  (4,3,'doc3v1');

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `t2` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

**Test queries**:
-- plan A1
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM t1) as d1 INNER JOIN ( SELECT t2.* FROM t2
    INNER JOIN (
    select did as mdid, min(hid) as mhid from t2 group by t2.did) as xmin ON t2.did = xmin.mdid and t2.HID = xmin.mhid

) as d2
ON d1.did = d2.did
GROUP BY d1.cfgID, d1.mid, d1.did, d2.hid, d2.did, d2.docname;

-- plan A2
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM t1) as d1 INNER JOIN ( SELECT t2.* FROM t2
    where t2.hid = (
select hid as mhid from t2 as xmin where t2.did = xmin.did order by hid asc limit 1
    )
    ) as d2
    ON d1.did = d2.did
GROUP BY d1.cfgID, d1.mid, d1.did, d2.hid, d2.did, d2.docname;

-- plan A3 ; switch off "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY"
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT * FROM t1) as d1 INNER JOIN ( SELECT t2.* FROM t2
where t2.hid = (select hid as mhid from t2 as xmin group by xmin.did having xmin.did = t2.did order by xmin.hid asc limit 1)
) as d2 ON d1.did = d2.did
GROUP BY d1.cfgID, d1.mid, d1.did, d2.hid, d2.did, d2.docname;

-- plan A4
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT * FROM t1) as d1 INNER JOIN ( SELECT t2.* FROM t2
where t2.hid = (select min(hid) as mhid from t2  as xmin group by xmin.did having xmin.did = t2.did)
) as d2 ON d1.did = d2.did
GROUP BY d1.cfgID, d1.mid, d1.did, d2.hid, d2.did, d2.docname;

-- plan B1
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM t1) as d1 INNER JOIN ( SELECT t2.* FROM t2) as d2
ON d1.did = d2.did
GROUP BY d1.cfgID, d1.mid, d1.did, d2.hid, d2.did, d2.docname
HAVING d2.hid = (select min(hid) as mhid from t2 where t2.did = d2.did group by t2.did)
;

-- plan B2
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM t1) as d1 INNER JOIN ( SELECT t2.* FROM t2) as d2
ON d1.did = d2.did
GROUP BY d1.cfgID, d1.mid, d1.did, d2.hid, d2.did, d2.docname
HAVING d2.hid = (select hid as mhid from t2 where t2.did = d2.did order by hid asc limit 1);

-- plan B3:
SELECT d1.*, d2.* FROM (SELECT * FROM t1) as d1 INNER JOIN
(SELECT t2.* FROM t2) as d2
 ON d1.did = d2.did
GROUP BY d1.cfgID, d1.mid, d1.did, d2.hid, d2.did, d2.docname
 HAVING d2.hid = (select hid as mhid from t2 as tx group by tx.did having tx.did = d2.did order by tx.hid asc limit 1)
;

-- plan B4
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT * FROM t1) as d1 INNER JOIN ( SELECT t2.* FROM t2
) as d2 ON d1.did = d2.did
GROUP BY d1.cfgID, d1.mid, d1.did, d2.hid, d2.did, d2.docname
HAVING d2.hid = (select min(hid) as mhid from t2  group by t2.did having t2.did = d2.did);

Comment: This question is a mess. Can't tell what your queries are when you break them up like that. Both plan A and plan B reference the `r1` table alias, but that table alias is defined only in plan A. I assume you have mixed up your queries as you wrote this question. Which makes me think you probably mixed up your results in your testing.

Comment: It's hard to tell, but I think you used `HAVING` in your plan B query assuming it is a synonym for `WHERE`, but it's not. You should learn about what `HAVING` is for; understand that it is for filtering *groups*, not filtering *rows*. When you using `HAVING` in a query with no `GROUP BY` clause, it implicitly causes the result to be reduced to one row, like if you use `SELECT COUNT(*)` without a `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: I have edited plan B to make it clear, that it uses the same GROUP BY as plan A.

Comment: Just write two complete queries. And post the *actual* queries you are running. Asking readers to piece together the queries to read them is not a good way to ask this question. Especially when you have made mistakes in transcription. How are we supposed to know if you have made any others? (For example `from docchange -  as d2` what does that even mean?)

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: I have moved the common part of the queries from separate code block into plan A & B. These are the actual queries used for testing, after simplification. Sorry for the single extra "-" typo.

Comment: @Blag The only possible simplification I see is removing the where clause for the docdistro table.The original queries had 5 joins and an additional order by ..

Comment: @Eperbab I was more speaking about the complete/verifiable part, like putting some test data or making a http://sqlfiddle.com/ sandbox for us to play.

Comment: @Blag I will try it tomorrow. I can't use actual data from production.

Comment: @Blag Test database and test queries added.

Comment: @Eperbab I take a look tomorrow ;)

Comment: Queries A3, A4, B4 added for testing.